How to put the dynamic receiver email adress into the reply
I successfully set up the dynamic receivers functionality in powermail as per the docs
Now i wanted to add the dynamic email to the reply mail (something like "your contact is: maxmuster@mustermail.com").
My first instinct was to just put this into the reply:
your contact is: {receivers1.email}

But this does not work. How can this be done?

I'm afraid, that only the data from the powermail form is parsed in the RTE field for the receiver-mail.
But you could override the receiver-mail template:
Ext:powermail/Resources/Private/Templates/Mail/ReceiverMail.html
In the main section you can access the receiver-mail via {email.receiverEmail}.
I.e. like this:
<f:section name="main">

    Your contact is: {email.receiverEmail}

    <vh:misc.variables mail="{mail}" type="mail" function="receiver">
        <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc_powermail">{powermail_rte}</f:format.html>
    </vh:misc.variables>

    <f:render partial="Misc/MarketingInformation" arguments="{marketingInfos:marketingInfos}" />
</f:section>

EDIT:
Be aware, that overriding this template will affect the receiver-mails of all Powermail forms.
